# Custom Function Return Value Error

Tags: function-construction, parametric-functions

I have created the following function which calculates the equation of a curve given it's slope as a derivative and a point.

```
FunctionName[fnPendiente_, puntoX_, puntoY_ ] := Module[
  {factorIntegrante, funcionExacta, solucionGeneral, sol, 
   valorConstante, solucionParticularCurva },
  ClearAll["Global`*"];
  solucionGeneral = DSolve[y'[x] == fnPendiente , y[x], x];
  solucionGeneral = Flatten[solucionGeneral];
  sol[x_] = y[x] /. solucionGeneral;
  valorConstante = Solve[sol[puntoX] == puntoY, C[1]];
  solucionParticularCurva[x_] = sol[x] /. Flatten[valorConstante];
  {solucionParticularCurva[x]}
  ]
```

But when I call the function:

```
FunctionName[Sin[3 x] - y[x], 0, 0]
```

I keep getting the following output:

```
{y[x]}
```

Is it something that I am missing or did incorrectly?

Comment: Have you tried to debug it step by step? p.s. ``ClearAll["Global`*"];`` is a really nasty side effect.

Comment: @Kuba Yes I tried but can't seem to figure out exactly where I went wrong. I inserted the ClearAll to see if that would help but it did not.

Comment: Use `DSolve[y'[x] == fnPendiente, y, x]` instead. Mathematica is doing some variable renaming when you define sol that is messing up your code.

Comment: @carl-wool Thx. That seems to have been the issue. Could you post it as an answer so I can accept it.